# Can a single DNS server provide different IP addresses for the same name based on sites, IP addresses or some other manner

Tags: domain-name-system

I have 3 sites, main site and 2 satellite offices that are connected via BOVPN.  The DNS servers are in the main site.  The end goal.
When in main site `sip.example.com` responds with Private IP say, 10.10.50.10
When in a remote site, `sip.example.com` needs to resolve to a public IP.

We already have split brain DNS in the main office.   Can I accomplish this without having local or different DNS servers?   I guess host file is an option, but hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: If domain.com has its own public IP that points to it, and you’re hosting the main DNS server, then yes just on the domain.com DNS record add a A record for the sip. with same public IP and go to your main router DNS and add a Privet IP that points to sip.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Split brain or other DNS tricks are possible. Read the documentation of your DNS, some have features to enable this in a single DNS server instance.

Or, do something simpler and return the same thing everywhere, "internal" and "external". For example, implement IPv6 and have an AAAA record resolving sip to something like `2001:db8:10:50::5061`. No shortage of public IPs when you have a /48 of them.